# How do I Convert an FXG image to Bitmapdata of fixed size

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to do this conversion so that I can determin the drag drop colour a puck lands on.

Anybody have any ideas, possibly involving:

ImageSnapshot
BitmapData

This would be in Flex 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the component is rendered on the screen; you can get BitMapData using something like this:

```
    static private function getUIComponentBitmapData( target : UIComponent ) : BitmapData
    { 
        var bd : BitmapData = new BitmapData( target.width, target.height,true);
        var m : Matrix = new Matrix();
        bd.draw( target, m );
        return bd;  
    }
```

[Note: I borrowed this method from a blog somewhere; but the URL I had on file for it is returning a 404]

Then you can turn that bitMapData into an image for display:

```
            var bitMap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitMapData);
            var image : Image = new Image();
            image.source = bitMap;
```

Comment: I managed to work something out, it appeared I needed to draw it somewhere before I extracted the bitmap, so I opened a transparent TitleWindow grabbed the image and closed it again, no one noticed.